# C# Remove everything after specific word

Tags: c#

My input is:

```
something1@email.com.;;
something2@email.eu,./
something3@email.org..
something4@email.netcdsfsd
```

What I want is to get rid of all characters after my "domains"(stored in array).

So output should be:

```
something1@email.com
something2@email.eu
something3@email.org
something4@email.net
```

My code is:

```
string[] domains = richTextBox_domains.Text.Split(';');
char[] specialchars = ".!#$%^&*()-_=+[]{}\\|;:'\",.<>/?".ToCharArray();
for (int x = 0; x < domains.Length; x++)
                        {
                            for (int y = 0; y < specialchars.Length; y++)
                            {
                                string check = domains[x] + specialchars[y];
                                string aftertmp = "." + after.Substring(after.IndexOf('.') + 1);
                                if (aftertmp == check)
                                    after = after.Replace(check, domains[x]);
                            }
                        }
```

It's working but not always and only for one character at the end.

I will be glad for help

Comment: You could solve it with a simple regex such as: `(.*?@.*?\.com|net|eu|org)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works fine

```
string[] s = { ".com",".net",".edu",".eu" };
string[] domain = new string[]
{
"something1@email.com.;;",
"something2@email.eu,./",
"something3@email.org..",
"something4@email.netcdsfsd"
};
string result = "";
        for (int m = 0; m < domain.Length; m++)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < s.Length; i++)
            {
                if (domain[m].IndexOf(s[i]) != -1)
                {
                    result = domain[m].Substring(0, domain[m].IndexOf(s[i])) + s[i];
                    MessageBox.Show(result);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

use regex to check email id and than store it in different array

```
      var regex1 = new Regex("(([-a-zA-Z0-9])|([-a-zA-Z0-9]{1,256}[@%._\+~#=][-a-zA-Z0-9])){1,10}\.[-a-zA-Z0-9]{1,10}\b",RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
      string[] domains = richTextBox_domains.Text.Split(';');
      List<string> l = new List<string>();
      for (int x = 0; x < domains.Length; x++)
      {
         var results = regex1.Matches(domains[x]);
         foreach (Match match in results)
         {
            l.Add(match.Groups[1].Value);
            MessageBox.Show(match.Groups[1].Value);
         }
      }

      string[] s = l.ToArray();// new array
```

hope this helps

Comment: Honestly I don;t really know what to do with regex. How can I export it to other richtextbox or array?

Comment: sorry my bad i thought u wanted all the matching values now the above code will work for you. This will also match the domain with two "periods"

Comment: Thanks. I got it now.